# Cloudflare UI is Driving me Insane, Does this button mean ON or OFF?

Tags: cloudflare

I seriously do not know which state of these buttons mean ON or OFF;
It is driving me insane!
Please tell me what means what before I start crying lol

Cloudflare amazingly confusing UI in my POV

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the green background suggests an on state and the label conveys the current status of the switch as opposed to the action it would perform.

Comment: I also asked in the cloudflare community, this is right! Uff...thanks!